# Correspondence between linear and affine functions in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

How to demonstrate that the correspondence between an affine function in $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ and a linear function in $\mathbb R^{n+1}\to\mathbb R^m$ is well defined?

I know any affine function $f(x)$ can be defined as $f(x) = l(x) + c$, where $l(x)$ is a linear function. But I don't know how to demonstrate that another function $g$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, $g(x,y) = l(x) + cy$ is correspondent to $f(x)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "the correspondence between a linear function in $\Bbb R^n \to\Bbb R^m$ and an affine function in $\Bbb R^{n+1} \to \Bbb R^m$;" it would help if you could use the same words with which the question was originally asked.  Are you looking for an *isomorphism* of these two spaces?

Comment: Note that the phrase "the function $g$ is isomorphic to $f$" is not a correct usage of the word "isomorphic".

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll make sure to use MathJax in my next questions, Saad.

Comment: I edited the question to use the original words in which it was formulated. You are right in the sense that the 'isomorphic' word was not mentioned there.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be the other way around, i.e., an _affine_ function in $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ corresponds to a _linear_ function in $\mathbb R^{n+1}\to\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: Yes amd, you are right. Just edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$, $y \in \Bbb R$.  Given a linear map $g:\Bbb R^{n+1} \to \Bbb R^m$, the function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ defined by 
$$
f(\mathbf x) = g(\mathbf x,1)
$$
is an affine transformation.